# FiddlerCore: HTTP Tunnel Issue

Tags: http, https, tunnel, fiddler

I have an application, and I am trying to intercept its requests with FiddlerCore.

Using Fiddler, I see the requests as follows:

[image]

(HTTP CONNECT tunnel into HTTPS request)

When using FiddlerCore, I am only seeing the initial HTTP CONNECT tunnel, and the application is not requesting. after that, stating:

> Failed to connect to server.

This is the code I'm using in the BeforeRequest method:

```
if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT"))
    {
        oSession["x-replywithtunnel"] = "FakeTunnel";
        return;
    }
```

And the output from the FiddlerCore program (upon running the application):

[image: Output from the FiddlerCore program]

The application is a Java application, which I had to create a keystore for using the FiddlerRoot certificate, and I am wondering if this is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Uses the FiddlerCore SSL certificate. FiddlerCore uses a different SSL certificate than Fiddler itself.

Comment: I’m not sure what the question is, and I’m doubly unsure how (whether) this answers it.  Did you figure out how to do what you wanted to do?  Did you determine that it is impossible to do what you wanted to do? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete; i.e., to make it more useful to the next person who has this problem and finds this page through a search engine.

Comment: The issue is simply that Fiddler was able to decrypt SSL using the keystore, but the same keystore was not able to decrypt SSL within FiddlerCore. The reasoning is that FiddlerCore uses a different SSL certificate, so upon creating the keystore with the correct FiddlerCore certificate, it started working.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to describe what you needed to do to get it to work.